# Excel showing a set of rows based on a specific value

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a sheet as below

[image]

I want my output to show

[image]

In short: How do I filter rows based on val1 and show all column1 data?

I want to show all column1 values where column2 has val1 as one of its values.

Comment: What does this have to do with `sorting`?

Comment: What's the difference in both images except `C` data?

Comment: @manishchrisian i want to show all values on column 1 that have val1 as value in column2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Advanced Filter

Criteria formula:

```
=OR(COUNTIFS($B$8:$B$17,$B$2,$A$8:$A$17,A8),A8="")
```

The `A8 = ""` is there so blank rows will be included

B2 contains the `val` you wish to filter on.

[image]